# Incorporating xtable with renderTable

Tags: r, shiny, xtable

I'm trying to get a basic xtable going and the math symbols are not showing up. I have the following snippets:

Server.R

```
output$FGR <- renderTable({
  results <- as.data.frame(createOutput()$resultsFGR)
  colnames(results) <- c("Prevalence","$HR|H_0$", "HR TPP", "A","B")
  results <- xtable(results)
  return(results)
}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

UI.R

```
tableOutput('FGR')
```

I've imported xtable in server.R.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use a `renderUI` - see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762412/math-mode-in-shiny-table/54762876#54762876)