# Rendering Katex in multiple tables in an R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, katex

I am using Stéphane Laurent's "EDIT 2" solution from the following post

> [Math mode in shiny table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762412/math-mode-in-shiny-table)

to render math in an R Shiny table. However, when there is more than one table present in the app only the first table is rendered (see reprex below).

I haven't been able to get this working with multiple tables so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)

js <- " 
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  if(event.name === 'table'){
    var matches = event.value.match(/(%%+[^%]+%%)/g);
    var newvalue = event.value;
    for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
      var code = '\\\\' + matches[i].slice(2,-2);
      newvalue = newvalue.replace(matches[i], katex.renderToString(code));
    }
    event.value = newvalue;
  }
})
" 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-9tPv11A+glH/on/wEu99NVwDPwkMQESOocs/ZGXPoIiLE8MU/qkqUcZ3zzL+6DuH", crossorigin="anonymous"),
    tags$script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.js", integrity="sha384-U8Vrjwb8fuHMt6ewaCy8uqeUXv4oitYACKdB0VziCerzt011iQ/0TqlSlv8MReCm", crossorigin="anonymous"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  mainPanel(
    numericInput("mean", "Enter mean", value = 1),
    numericInput("mean_2", "Enter 2nd mean", value = 2),
    tableOutput("table"),
    tableOutput("table_2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(2)
    y <- rnorm(2, input$mean)
    tab <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = c("hello", "%%gamma%%%%delta%%"))
    rownames(tab) <- c("%%alpha%%", "%%beta%%")
    tab
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
  output$table_2 <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(2)
    y <- rnorm(2, input$mean_2)
    tab <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = c("hello", "%%eta%%%%epsilon%%"))
    rownames(tab) <- c("%%alpha%%", "%%beta%%")
    tab
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:**

A second problem is how this is achievable within a module when the table event is wrapped in ns(). Please find a reprex below demonstrating this problem:

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

source("table1.R")
source("table2.R")

ui = dashboardPage(

header = dashboardHeader(),

body = dashboardBody(
  
  tabItems(
    
    tabItem(tabName = "table_1",
            table1UI(id = "table1id")),
    
    tabItem(tabName = "table_2",
            table2UI(id = "table2id"))
    
    ) # Closes tabItems

), # Closes dashboard body

sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  
  width = 272.25, # Header is 230px button is 42.5px
  
  minified = FALSE,
  
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Table 1", tabName = "table_1", icon = icon("chalkboard-teacher"))),
    menuItem("Table 2", tabName = "table_2", icon = icon("chalkboard-teacher")))

) # Closes UI

server = function(input, output, session) { 

callModule(module = table1,
           id = "table1id")

callModule(module = table2,
           id = "table2id")


} # Closes Server

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**table1.R**

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  if(event.name === 'table_1'){
    var matches = event.value.match(/(%%+[^%]+%%)/g);
    var newvalue = event.value;
    for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
      var code = '\\\\' + matches[i].slice(2,-2);
      newvalue = newvalue.replace(matches[i], katex.renderToString(code));
    }
    event.value = newvalue;
  }
})
"

table1UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-9tPv11A+glH/on/wEu99NVwDPwkMQESOocs/ZGXPoIiLE8MU/qkqUcZ3zzL+6DuH", crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.js", integrity="sha384-U8Vrjwb8fuHMt6ewaCy8uqeUXv4oitYACKdB0VziCerzt011iQ/0TqlSlv8MReCm", crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    
    tagList(
    numericInput(ns("mean"), "Enter mean", value = 2),
    tableOutput(outputId = ns("table_1"))
    ))
} # Closes UI

table1 <- function(input, output, session, mean) {
  
  output$table_1 <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(2)
    y <- rnorm(2, input$mean)
    tab <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = c("hello", "%%gamma%%%%delta%%"))
    rownames(tab) <- c("%%alpha%%", "%%beta%%")
    tab
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
} # Closes server
```

**table2.R**

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  if(event.name === 'table_2'){
    var matches = event.value.match(/(%%+[^%]+%%)/g);
    var newvalue = event.value;
    for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
      var code = '\\\\' + matches[i].slice(2,-2);
      newvalue = newvalue.replace(matches[i], katex.renderToString(code));
    }
    event.value = newvalue;
  }
})
"

table2UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-9tPv11A+glH/on/wEu99NVwDPwkMQESOocs/ZGXPoIiLE8MU/qkqUcZ3zzL+6DuH", crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.js", integrity="sha384-U8Vrjwb8fuHMt6ewaCy8uqeUXv4oitYACKdB0VziCerzt011iQ/0TqlSlv8MReCm", crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    
    tagList(
    numericInput(ns("mean_2"), "Enter 2nd mean", value = 2),
    tableOutput(outputId = ns("table_2"))
    ))
} # Closes UI

table2 <- function(input, output, session, mean_2) {
  
  output$table_2 <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(2)
    y <- rnorm(2, input$mean_2)
    tab <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = c("hello", "%%eta%%%%epsilon%%"))
    rownames(tab) <- c("%%alpha%%", "%%beta%%")
    tab
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
} # Closes server
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
if(event.name === 'table')
```

with

```
if(event.name === 'table' || event.name === 'table_2')
```

---

The app using modules:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

table1UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidRow(
    tagList(
      numericInput(ns("mean"), "Enter mean", value = 2),
      tableOutput(outputId = ns("table_1"))
    )
  )
  
} # Closes UI

table1 <- function(input, output, session, mean) {
  
  output$table_1 <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(2)
    y <- rnorm(2, input$mean)
    tab <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = c("hello", "%%gamma%%%%delta%%"))
    rownames(tab) <- c("%%alpha%%", "%%beta%%")
    tab
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
} # Closes server

table2UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidRow(
    tagList(
      numericInput(ns("mean_2"), "Enter 2nd mean", value = 2),
      tableOutput(outputId = ns("table_2"))
    )
  )
  
} # Closes UI

table2 <- function(input, output, session, mean_2) {
  
  output$table_2 <- renderTable({
    x <- rnorm(2)
    y <- rnorm(2, input$mean_2)
    tab <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = c("hello", "%%eta%%%%epsilon%%"))
    rownames(tab) <- c("%%alpha%%", "%%beta%%")
    tab
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
} # Closes server

js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  if((/table_1$/).test(event.name) || (/table_2$/).test(event.name)){
    var matches = event.value.match(/(%%+[^%]+%%)/g);
    var newvalue = event.value;
    for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
      var code = '\\\\' + matches[i].slice(2,-2);
      newvalue = newvalue.replace(matches[i], katex.renderToString(code));
    }
    event.value = newvalue;
  }
})
"

ui = dashboardPage(
  
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  
  body = dashboardBody(
    
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-9tPv11A+glH/on/wEu99NVwDPwkMQESOocs/ZGXPoIiLE8MU/qkqUcZ3zzL+6DuH", crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-beta/dist/katex.min.js", integrity="sha384-U8Vrjwb8fuHMt6ewaCy8uqeUXv4oitYACKdB0VziCerzt011iQ/0TqlSlv8MReCm", crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(tabName = "table_1",
              table1UI(id = "table1id")),
      
      tabItem(tabName = "table_2",
              table2UI(id = "table2id"))
      
    ) # Closes tabItems
    
  ), # Closes dashboard body
  
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    
    width = 272.25, # Header is 230px button is 42.5px
    
    minified = FALSE,
    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Table 1", tabName = "table_1", icon = icon("chalkboard-teacher")),
      menuItem("Table 2", tabName = "table_2", icon = icon("chalkboard-teacher"))
    )
    
  )
  
) # Closes UI

server = function(input, output, session) { 
  
  callModule(module = table1,
             id = "table1id")
  
  callModule(module = table2,
             id = "table2id")
  
} # Closes Server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Laurent thanks! This has revealed another problem. Is it possible to refer to the event.name, i.e table_1 or table_2 (see reprex in original post) when they are wrapped in ns() within a module? Thanks again!

Comment: @ZekeMarshall `ns("table_2")` returns `"namespace-table2"`. The easiest way is to do `if((/table_2$/).test(event.name))`. In JavaScript, `/table_2$/` is a regular expression, it represents all strings which end with `table_2`.

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Laurent thanks again! How would this work in the context of the reprex? I've tried a to replace `if(event.name === 'table_1')` with `if((/table_1$/).test(event.name))`, and replace `'table_1'` with `'/table_1$/'`, but neither are working. Thanks again for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane Laurent! This works perfectly!